# Shouldn't this question about working around Ethernet problems be reopened?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, reopen-request

The question we are talking about:

- [How to get around NVM Checksum error (PXE-E05) to make the ethernet work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441420/how-to-get-around-nvm-checksum-error-pxe-e05-to-make-the-ethernet-work-on-ubun)

I had cast the first vote for closure on this question on 31st March as it was unclear and didn't provide much detail.

The OP later edited the question and gave a thorough account to the point where the question wasn't unclear anymore. He even solved it himself by providing a good and detailed answer on how to get around the issue. 5 days later the question still got closed as unclear - I am not sure why/how, but okay.

Then the [question came into the Reopen Review queue](https://askubuntu.com/review/reopen/244335) and I nominated to reopen it. The review completed with 2 votes in favor and 3 against reopening. As of now, all the reopen votes have been cleared by the system and I can't re-nominate to reopen it. Can this please be reopened?

Comment: Maybe you can update your answer saying that the Q has been reopened? Good follow-up, though!

Answer (score 2):

The question has already been reopened.  [It was reopened about 7 hours ago.](https://askubuntu.com/posts/441420/revisions)

Comment: Yup... It got reopened after I posted this meta question... Not sure why did you create this answer mentioning the time when it got reopened... I hope you are not mistaking that I posted this meta question after reopening :)